# Is there a way I can use uri instead of require for React Native Prop types?

Tags: reactjs, image, react-native, react-proptypes

When I try to use `uri`, the image does not show and I want to avoid local images because I can't dynamically use `require`.

```
static propTypes = {
    ...ViewPropTypes,
    initialPage: PropTypes.number,
    pager: PropTypes.instanceOf(IndicatorViewPager),
    tabs: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
        text: PropTypes.string,
        iconSource: Image.propTypes.source, <-- Here is the problem
        selectedIconSource: Image.propTypes.source
    })).isRequired,
}
```

Is there a way I can make this accept uri sources? Also here is the rest of my code:

```
let tabs = [{
    text: `${this.state.tags.toLowerCase()}`,
    iconSource: 'https://www.exmaple.com/img/cookies.png',
    selectedIconSource: require("../img/bluep.png")
}];
```

Comment: is this issue happens in ios simulator / device ?

Comment: @Adarsh I haven't tested this on ios, I'm on an Android physical device

Comment: source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png'}}, is this what you what?

Comment: @Adarsh Yes for iconSource on the first code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing a couple of things. An Image source can be a require() or a uri, but the uri is not just a string you can pass to the source prop of the Image. It needs to be an object that has a uri string prop, like this:

```
<Image source={{uri: 'http://myimageurl.com'}}/>
```

Second, with prop types you are just defining which props validation you want to use at Debug time. It has nothing to do with your Image not showing up. If you send a wrong prop, it will show you a Yellow warning screen.

Lastly, your problem is that you are just sending the prop as a string, and you need to send the object.

So, without seeing much of the rest of the code, you should be fine changing this part:

```
let tabs = [{
    text: `${this.state.tags.toLowerCase()}`,
    iconSource: {uri: 'https://www.exmaple.com/img/cookies.png'},
    selectedIconSource: require("../img/bluep.png")
}];
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!!